# Algorithm to fill a grid with n elements for a given aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I need to find the dimensions of a grid to be filled by n elements, given an aspect ratio. The grid doesn't have to be full.

For instance, if n=8 and the aspect ratio is 1:1, I should get a grid of 3 x 3. With 8 elements in it I'd be left with an empty cell :

```
***
***
**
```

Of if n=13 and the aspect ratio is 1:2, I'd get a 6 x 3 grid :

```
******
******
*
```

I'm pretty sure that there exists a way to calculate this for any n and and any ratio, but I couldn't find anything on the web (probably because I don't know the keywords for this kind of problem).

*Note : this is for a visualization I'm making with Javascript but I don't need JS code, just an algorithm.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1** - find multiplicator: 
 
If aspect ratio is 3:4, then `a=3`, `b=4`, `n = elements` 
`multi = math.ceil(   SQRT(n / (a*b))  )`. 
**Step 2** - find dimensions: 
`dim1 = a * multi`; 
`dim2 = b * multi`; 
 
**Example.** 
 
n = 59. a = 2, b = 3.

```
 multi = math.ceil  (SQRT (59 / (2*3))) = math.ceil(  sqrt(9.833)  ) = 4
 dim1 = 2*4 = 8; 
 dim2 = 3*4 = 12;
```

8*12 = 96 (so 59 fits into it). Previous is 54 (6x9) - it was too small. 
 
**Example 2.** 
n = 24. a = 1, b = 2.

```
 multi = math.ceil  (SQRT (24 / (1*2))) = math.ceil(  sqrt(12)  ) = 4
 dim1 = 1*4 = 4; 
 dim2 = 2*4 = 8;
```

4*8 = 32 (so 24 fits into it). 
 
**Example 3 (exactly full).** 
n = 27. a = 1, b = 3.

```
 multi = math.ceil  (SQRT (27 / (1*3))) = math.ceil(  sqrt(9)  ) = 3
 dim1 = 1*3 = 3; 
 dim2 = 3*3 = 9;
```

3*9 = 27 (so 27 (border value) fits into it).